# Best Approach to create a view with Save Cancel buttons

Tags: ios

I would like to add a screen in my application with the common cancel and save button seen in iPhone. Do I need to develop this kind of view with save/cancel button or there an easier standard way to do create this screen

regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just used UINavigatorController.